# How do I composite render layers in 2.69 using Cycles?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I'm using 2.69 Cycles and I have a plane on one render layer and a cube on a second render layer. Also, under Render -> Film, I have Transparent selected so both layers have no background color.

I want the final image to be the cube and the plane, but I can't figure out which nodes to use to do that.

If I use a Mix node with Factor set to 0.5, the composited image only shows where the plane and cube visually overlap.

How can I get the final composite to show the full cube and the full plane?

Here is the link to the blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENSmZaOGJMaGhxczQ/edit?usp=sharing

And here is my Compositing screen:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an *Alpha Over* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*>Add node > Color > Alpha Over*):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel very sheepish...I thought I tried that but obviously I was confused. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have the inputs back-to-front you will see the plane over the cube, appearing to cut the cube off at the edge of the plane, which probably threw you off.

Comment: Also, consider wiring the Z output from your render layers up to the Z input on the composite and viewer as that will restore any overlaps (imagine an arm and hand wrapping around an object, where the body is on the "back" layer and the "object" being held is on the "near" layer.