# Transparent render layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am trying to figure out how to work with render layers. Now I have two render layers connected to the output via *Alpha Over* node. But when I render the composite output layer is not the combined output of the two separate render layers. What is my stupidity?

[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/how-do-i-composite-render-layers-in-2-69-using-cycles, more explanation: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3003/3710

Comment: Cycles or internal? The question is tagged with cycles, but you are using internal (screenshot).

Comment: I edited my question. How to get the composite output I want (the combined render layers) ?

Comment: You want to have both cubes, right? Please try to explain what is wrong with 3pointedit's answer and what you don't understand exactly.

Comment: done. see my added comment

Comment: I think I understand this idea of transparency now. But this means that if i want a combined layer of two render layers (with a background) I have to define a third render layer that consists of both individual render layers ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29003/discussion-between-jan-scherders-and-poor).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be that you are not actually providing the compositor with any transparency. The alpha output socket from the scene node will just be a solid white unless you check the following properties:

**Blender Internal:** Turn on Shading > alpha > transparent, in render properties.

**Cycles:** Turn on film > transparent, in render properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to work with transparency / alpha channels. Maybe I was not very clear in my question. I have now added a new picture showing the composite layer in cycles blender. Why is only one render layer in the composite layer ? I want both render layers in the composite layer. How to do that ?

Comment: @JanScherders Simply because your images (see the render layer preview window) are not transparent. As I suggested, read [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/using-scenes-and-render-layers-to-composite-an-object-isolated-on-white-backgrou/3003#3003) carefully. Here is a blend, open it and hit F12: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/488/