# How to get rid of an object's reflection?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, compositing-nodes, render-layers

I am creating a logo for a friend (not getting paid), and I want to figure out a way to get rid of one object's reflection against another without removing the other object's reflectivity. If you look at the image, the "e" in Jewel shows up against the diamond and I don't want it to. Can I place the Jewel on a different layer with an alpha layer background in order to insert it into the image without the diamond having a reflection of it, and then use the compositor to overlay one on top of the other?

How would I go about this? I've looked up tutorials online on how to use the compositor, and they all involve an "image" node and a "compositor" node, but I can't seem to find these under the "add node" button, and I've been searching for a while.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/how-do-i-composite-render-layers-in-2-69-using-cycles?rq=1 and here you can find a more in depth explanation (skip the "divide" node part): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/using-scenes-and-render-layers-to-composite-an-object-isolated-on-white-backgrou?rq=1

Comment: what render engine are you using?

Comment: @Carlo I can't find anything in either of those about how to get a render layer node.

Comment: @cegaton I'm using Cycles

Comment: You can find the *Render Layer node* in the *Input* section/tab of the *Add* menu (or you can use the *Search* function)

Comment: Oh. I was looking on the materials node editor, not the compositor node editor. I still don't really know how to use the compositor or its node editor. I'll look up some tutorials.

Answer (score 14):

In cycles you can disable the reflection of the selected object. In the properties window go to Cycles Settings and disable **[Ray Visibility](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html?highlight=ray%20visibility#ray-visibility)** for glossy.

Here's example of how you can make the text objects disappear from the reflection of the cube:

[image]